# How important foam mattresses for you health?

Tags: sleep, health-informatics

why do you need them?

what benefits you get from it?

If you don't have problem with your back, does it make sense to use them?

Answer (score 1):

I tried a Tempur mattress for a couple of years. I have no back problems. I found it too hot and didn't like the feeling of sleeping in a depression.

In future I will stick to a good quality mattress with a high spring-count.

Comment: Hi, supfunc, welcome to Health Stack Exchange. [References are strongly encouraged](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1/2192) in answers; personal anecdotes alone are rarely as helpful.